# Covering clean surfaces on Pesach

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, passover, chametz-leaven

There is a prohibition of eating even a crumb of chametz on Pesach. After cleaning a surface with bleach (or the like), any remnant of chametz is not considered fitting for a dog to eat and certainly not subject to the prohibition of 'bal yiraeh' and 'bal yimatzei'.

If you are not going to place any hot/sharp tasting food item on surface (where there may be transference of 'taste') is there a need to cover (and if so, double cover) such a surface on Pesach?

(For general principles on this topic see Mishneh Berura on taarovet chametz)

Comment: What reasoning would exist that one would think it was required? ***IF*** there is no possibility of transfer of ta'am and no halachic chametz of any kind, how would there ever be a requirement? The only concerns are that perhaps a surface was not properly cleaned (taken care of with your initial statements) or that tam beluyah would transfer into other food/kelim (negated by your second paragraph).

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky I ask because there are many around me that cover ALL surfaces even when cleaned/bleached, etc. I wanted to find positive statements about the lack of need to cover all surfaces if they are indeed clean.